# Whats the standard of defining an empty object in JSON

Tags: json

I have an issue with my application. It is returning a JSON file of an array of objects. The application is defining an empty object inside the array of objects as text value string whose value is defined as an object in the other element of array. Please see the value of the key "b" in the example.

For Eg:

```
    {
       "result": [{
                     "a": "1",
                     "b": {
                            "c1": "31",
                            "c2": "32"
                            }
                 }, {
                     "a": "5",
                      "b": ""
                 }

           ]

     }
```

I want to know if that is a correct way of defining the key "b" as an empty object.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty object is defined by `{}`:

```
"b": {}
```

I.e. use the usual object delimiters but don't add any key-values.

What you defined is an empty *string*.

Comment: But this comes as valid JSON in most of the JSON validatiors online. Why is that? Please refer me to if there is any documentation related to it.

Comment: What comes as valid? `"b": ""`? Of course, it is valid JSON, but it is not what you want according to your description. You said you wanted an *object*. An empty object is `{}`. `""` is an empty *string*, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, an object is defined with `{ }`, which is exactly what you would represent an empty object as.

```
{
  "result": [
     {
       "a": "1",
       "b": {
          "c1": "31",
          "c2": "32"
        }
      }, {
        "a": "5",
        "b": { }
      }

  ]

}
```